# php form cannot submit which access by ajax

Tags: php

I try to submit form using isset($_POST(['submit'])) in php file which access through ajax but it doesn't work. Please find the code snippets below:

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: './B.php',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) 
  { $("#showB").html(data);}
  });
});
</script>
<body>

<table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><div id="showB"></div></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

B.php:

```
 <html>
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {

$message= "halo";
  }  
?>
<head>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>

        <tr>
            <td style="height: 30px"></td>
<td style="height: 30px"><?php if(!empty($message)) { echo     $message; } ?></td>
            <td style="height: 30px"></td>
            <td style="height: 30px; width: 298px;"></td>

        </tr>
<form method="post" action="halo.php">  
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
&nbsp;<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes"/></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 298px">
            &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
<td style="width: 244px; height: 26px;"><h5>Effective Width&nbsp;:&nbsp;</h5></td>
<td style="width: 262px; height: 26px;"><input name="effectivewidth" type="text"/></td>
            <td style="width: 261px; height: 26px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 298px; height: 26px;"></td>

        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

The form in B.php cannot be submit with no error. Please help. thanks

Comment: Sidenote: You can shorten this `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {` to just `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` since there' no text/input being passed "in" it.

Comment: i think the url is wrong in your ajax code. It must be `B.php` or `../B.php`

Comment: You aren't posting any **data** to it, which is why your variable is not set

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not passing any data over post.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: './B.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { submit: "submit"},
  success: function(data) 
  { $("#showB").html(data);}
  });
});
</script>
```

Pass the appropriate `data` to `$.ajax`

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm quite new in ajax. It still doesnt work. Just to clarify that i'm not passing the variable from A.php to B.php. I just want to submit the B.php to same page.